How to set timeout while using @HttpExchange with RestClient in Spring Boot
I want to set request timeout while making API calls using @PostExchange or @GetExchange with RestClient.
Below is the RestClient configuration:
    @Bean
    public BonusPayoutRestClient restClient() {
        RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("%s://%s/".formatted(protocol, internalApiUrl))
                .build();
        RestClientAdapter adapter = RestClientAdapter.create(restClient);
        HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(adapter)
                .build();
        return factory.createClient(BonusPayoutRestClient.class);
    }

I've tried updating the configuration like below and still does not work.
@Bean
public BonusPayoutRestClient restClient() {
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("%s://%s/".formatted(protocol, internalApiUrl))
            .requestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory())
            .build();
    RestClientAdapter adapter = RestClientAdapter.create(restClient);
    HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(adapter)
            .build();
    return factory.createClient(BonusPayoutRestClient.class);
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000);
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}

NOTE: I am not getting any errors, its just that whatever timeout I try to set does not seem to get picked up. If I set it to 100, 1000 or 10000, the behaviour is the same.

what do u mean it's not working ? is it not throwing any timeout errors ?

@RyuzakiL the timeout I'm setting is not taken, even if I change the value to 100, 1000 or 10000, it seems to be waiting for longer period

Updating code to user SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory seems to make things work. I would still like to know why it did not work with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory. Going with this solution for now.
@Bean
public BonusPayoutRestClient restClient() {
    RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("%s://%s/".formatted(protocol, internalApiUrl))
            .requestFactory(getClientHttpRequestFactory())
            .build();
    RestClientAdapter adapter = RestClientAdapter.create(restClient);
    HttpServiceProxyFactory factory = HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(adapter)
            .build();
    return factory.createClient(BonusPayoutRestClient.class);
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis));
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeoutMillis));
    return simpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
}

